# How do I simplify inverse tangent?

Tags: calculus

How do I simplify $\sec(\arctan(x/5))$?
I tried using the formula but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hint: let theta = arctan(x/5).  then take tangent of both sides.  Draw a triangle that is correctly labeled by this relationship and then take secant of theta.

Comment: @mathamphetamines. May I ask hoçw you chose a so nice name ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Haha, just came to me one day :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec(\arctan(x/5))$$ 
Can be simplified by using 
$$
\tan^2 y + 1 = \sec^2 y
$$

Now let the argument in the expression you are trying to simplify be $y$.

We have

$$
\sec y  = \sqrt{\tan^2 y + 1}
$$

Or 
$$
\sec(\arctan(x/5)) =  \sqrt{\tan^2 \left((\arctan(x/5)\right)+ 1}
$$

Also, utilise 
$$
\tan \left(\arctan x \right) = x\\
\tan^2 x = \left(\tan x\right)^2.
$$
Can you see it now?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle and label one of the angles $\theta$.

If $\theta = \arctan(x/5)$ then the (non-hypotenuse) side opposite $\theta$ can be $x$, and the side adjacent $\theta$ will be $5$.

The hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2+25}$ by the Pythagorean theorem.

Now, $\sec \theta = 1/\cos \theta$, which is the hypotenuse divided by the adjacent side:

$$\sec(\arctan(x/5)) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 25}}{5}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Say $\arctan(x/5)= \alpha$. You have $\tan\alpha=x/5$. Find $\sec(\alpha)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** draw a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $<A = 90^\circ$, $AB = x, AC = 5$, and $\theta = \arctan(x/5) = <B$

Answer (score 0):

You can figure this out by drawing the triangle that these quantities describe.

For $\arctan\frac{x}{5}$, we are describing a right triangle with an angle $\theta$ which is opposite a side with length $x$ and adjacent to a side with length 5. Therefore the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{25+x^2}$. Now we want to say what $\sec \theta$ is equal to. $\sec\theta = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ and $\cos\theta = \frac{5}{\sqrt{25+x^2}} \Rightarrow \sec \theta = \frac{\sqrt{25+x^2}}{5}$